# Video made from image collection takes a lot of time to play

Tags: ios, multithreading, avfoundation, swift4

I am trying to make a video editor in which I have done the following:

1)Collected photos from user gallery.

2)Converted that array of photos in videos .

3)Added animations to videos.

4)Played Videos

The code i have done for that are as follows:-

1)Collected photos from user gallery.

```
    func openImagePicker(){
        let customColor = UIColor.init(red: 64.0/255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 144.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let customCameraColor = UIColor.init(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 1.0/255.0, blue: 236.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        pickerViewController.numberOfPhotoToSelect = 5;        pickerViewController.theme.titleLabelTextColor = UIColor.white
        pickerViewController.theme.navigationBarBackgroundColor = customColor
        pickerViewController.theme.tintColor = UIColor.white
        pickerViewController.theme.orderTintColor = customCameraColor
        pickerViewController.theme.cameraVeilColor = customCameraColor
        pickerViewController.theme.cameraIconColor = UIColor.white
        pickerViewController.theme.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        self.yms_presentCustomAlbumPhotoView(pickerViewController, delegate: self)

    }

    func photoPickerViewController(_ picker: YMSPhotoPickerViewController!, didFinishPickingImages photoAssets: [PHAsset]!) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.selectedImageArray =  NSMutableArray()
            let imageManager = PHImageManager.init()
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions.init()
            options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
            options.resizeMode = .exact
            options.isSynchronous = true
            for asset: PHAsset in photoAssets
            {
                let targetSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.size.width
                    , height:self.view.frame.size.width)
                imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize:targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in
                    self.selectedImageArray.add(image!)
                })
            }

            let imageVideaMakerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideoEditorController") as! VideoEditorController

            imageVideaMakerController.selectedImageArray = self.selectedImageArray as! [UIImage]
            self.navigationController!.pushViewController(imageVideaMakerController, animated: true)

        }
    }
```

2)Converted that array of photos in videos .

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

         setUpInitialView()
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    //MARK:- Custom Methods
    func setUpInitialView(){
        let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
        loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.indeterminate
        loadingNotification.label.text = "Loading"

        buildVideoFromImageArray()
        //filterScrollContents()
    }

func buildVideoFromImageArray() {

        imageArrayToVideoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/video1.MP4")
        removeFileAtURLIfExists(url: imageArrayToVideoURL)
        guard let videoWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: imageArrayToVideoURL as URL, fileType: AVFileType.mp4) else {
            fatalError("AVAssetWriter error")
        }
        let outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.width)), AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.height))] as [String : Any]
        guard videoWriter.canApply(outputSettings: outputSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaType.video) else {
            fatalError("Negative : Can't apply the Output settings...")
        }
        let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
        let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB), kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.width)), kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.height))]
        let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)
        if videoWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) {
            videoWriter.add(videoWriterInput)
        }
        if videoWriter.startWriting() {
            let zeroTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(imagesPerSecond),Int32(1))
            videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: zeroTime)

            assert(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil)
            let media_queue = DispatchQueue(label: "mediaInputQueue")
            videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: media_queue, using: { () -> Void in
                let fps: Int32 = 1
                let framePerSecond: Int64 = Int64(self.imagesPerSecond)
                let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(Int64(self.imagesPerSecond), fps)
                var frameCount: Int64 = 0
                var appendSucceeded = true
                var newImageArr = self.selectedImageArray
                while (!newImageArr.isEmpty) {
                    if (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                        let nextPhoto = newImageArr.remove(at: 0)
                        let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount * framePerSecond, fps)
                        let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)
                        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
                        let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)
                        if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, status == 0 {
                            let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer
                            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
                            let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                            let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(self.outputSize.width), height: Int(self.outputSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(managedPixelBuffer), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
                            context!.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(self.outputSize.width), height: CGFloat(self.outputSize.height)))
                            let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.width) / nextPhoto.size.width
                            let verticalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.height) / nextPhoto.size.height
                            //let aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
                            let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFit
                            let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: nextPhoto.size.width * aspectRatio, height: nextPhoto.size.height * aspectRatio)
                            let x = newSize.width < self.outputSize.width ? (self.outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
                            let y = newSize.height < self.outputSize.height ? (self.outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0
                            context?.draw(nextPhoto.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
                            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to allocate pixel buffer")
                            appendSucceeded = false
                        }
                    }
                    if !appendSucceeded {
                        break
                    }
                    frameCount += 1
                }
                videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                videoWriter.finishWriting { () -> Void in
                    print("-----video1 url = \(self.imageArrayToVideoURL)")
                    self.globalVideoURL = self.imageArrayToVideoURL

                    self.asset = AVAsset.init(url:self.imageArrayToVideoURL as URL)

                    self.exportVideoWithAnimation()
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

3)Added animations to videos.

```
func exportVideoWithAnimation() {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let track =  self.asset?.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)
        let videoTrack:AVAssetTrack = track![0] as AVAssetTrack
        let timerange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, (self.asset?.duration)!)

        let compositionVideoTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

        do {
            try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(timerange, of: videoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
            compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        //if your video has sound, you don’t need to check this
        if self.audioIsEnabled {
            let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

            for audioTrack in (self.asset?.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio))! {
                do {
                    try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        let size = videoTrack.naturalSize

        let videolayer = CALayer()
        videolayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        let parentlayer = CALayer()
        parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //this is the animation part
        var time = [0.00001, 3, 6, 9, 12] //I used this time array to determine the start time of a frame animation. Each frame will stay for 3 secs, thats why their difference is 3
        var imgarray = self.selectedImageArray

        for image in 0..<self.selectedImageArray.count {


            let nextPhoto = imgarray[image]

            let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.width) / nextPhoto.size.width
            let verticalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.height) / nextPhoto.size.height
            let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
            let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: nextPhoto.size.width * aspectRatio, height: nextPhoto.size.height * aspectRatio)
            let x = newSize.width < self.outputSize.width ? (self.outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
            let y = newSize.height < self.outputSize.height ? (self.outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0
            let blackLayer = CALayer()
            ///#7. opacity(1->0)(top->bottom)///
            //#3. top->bottom///
            //MARK:- Animations==================================
            ///#1. left->right///
            if(self.globalSelectedTransitionTag == 0){

                blackLayer.frame = CGRect(x: -videoTrack.naturalSize.width, y: 0, width: videoTrack.naturalSize.width, height: videoTrack.naturalSize.height)
                blackLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

                let imageLayer = CALayer()
                imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
                imageLayer.contents = imgarray[image].cgImage
                blackLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)


                let animation = CABasicAnimation()
                animation.keyPath = "position.x"
                animation.fromValue = -videoTrack.naturalSize.width
                animation.toValue = 5 * (videoTrack.naturalSize.width)
                animation.duration = 5
                animation.beginTime = CFTimeInterval(time[image])
                animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
                animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
                blackLayer.add(animation, forKey: "opacity")
            }

            parentlayer.addSublayer(blackLayer)
        }        
        let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        layercomposition.renderSize = size

        layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, in: parentlayer)
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, composition.duration)
        let videotrack = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack
        let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videotrack)
        instruction.layerInstructions = [layerinstruction]
        layercomposition.instructions = [instruction]
        if(fromTransition){
            self.globalrVideoComposition = layercomposition
        }
        let animatedVideoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/video2.mp4")
        self.removeFileAtURLIfExists(url: animatedVideoURL)

        guard let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {return}
        assetExport.videoComposition = self.globalrVideoComposition
        assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        assetExport.outputURL = animatedVideoURL as URL
        print("****** animatedVideoURL *****",animatedVideoURL)
        assetExport.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            switch assetExport.status{
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            default:
                print("Exported")

                if(self.fromPlayVideo){
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.globalVideoURL = animatedVideoURL; self.playVideoInPlayer(animatedVideoURL: animatedVideoURL as URL)
                    }
                }else if(self.fromSave){

                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: animatedVideoURL as URL)
                        print("222222 animatedVideoURL",animatedVideoURL)



                    }) { saved, error in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.view, animated: true)
                        }

                        if saved {

                            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                            print("The task is done,enjoy now!")
                            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }else{

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

4)Played Videos

```
func playVideoInPlayer(animatedVideoURL:URL){

        if(globalFilterName != nil){
            self.asset = AVAsset.init(url:animatedVideoURL as URL)
            let newPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(asset:self.asset);
            newPlayerItem.videoComposition=globalrVideoComposition
            self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem:newPlayerItem)
        }else{
            let newPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url:animatedVideoURL)
            self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem:newPlayerItem)
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.finishedPlaying(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object:nil)
        self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player:self.player)
        let width: CGFloat = self.videoContainerView.frame.size.width
        let height: CGFloat = self.videoContainerView.frame.size.height
        self.playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0, width: width, height: height)
        self.playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        self.videoContainerView.layer.addSublayer( self.playerLayer)

        self.playPauseBtn.isHidden = false

        self.playPauseBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named:"pause"), for:.normal)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for:self.view, animated:true)
            self.player.play()
        }

    }
```

This whole task is woking fine the only problem is ,it is taking a lot of time to play the video with all setups(conversion image to video and adding animations).
Please help me to reduce the time so that the user has to not wait for long time when they land to play video after collecting images from imagepicker.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to see what the problem is. Exporting video takes time.

Comment: @matt ,I have done some changes to question,hope it will help to understand better now.